# Wait/Sleep in PLSQL

Tags: asynchronous, plsql, locking

I want to test sync/async call to a procedure named pro1. For that purpose, I want to put lock call in pro1.

```
DECLARE
    t INTEGER;
BEGIN
    t := 60;
    DBMS_LOCK.sleep(t);
END;
/
```

Just want to make sure, would that wait/lock a sync call? i.e. my proc1 wouldn't exit untill that lock is finished?

P.S:
While the **Proc1** is being run, there is another procedure. I want to test its execution while there is a lock on connection by **Pro1**

Comment: Contrary to what the name of the package might suggest, `DBMS_LOCK.sleep` does not really lock anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DBMS_LOCK.sleep` will put the session process to sleep, i-e: this session will do nothing for 60 seconds.

I'm not sure what you mean by a "lock on connection". If the session that runs the `sleep` procedure has any lock pending, they will be kept during the sleep and other sessions that might be blocked by it will have to wait for the first session to either commit or rollback as usual.

Comment: okay the thing is, in our application, there are time events which are being called as ***jobs***. and it happens when the job is running, it takes time and meantime, if we ***undeploy*** the app, it get exception that there is database lock. What we want to do, is to call that ***job*** asynchronously using **DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('name',false)**. To test this, I want to run a simple job and call sleep in it, so that i takes time. and meantime, I wanna see if the undeployement halts or not

Comment: @alee: the job that calls the `sleep` proc will do nothing while it sleeps. It will also not return before the end of the sleep, therefore the total execution will take time.